# ContentResolver.query() で "Invalid token limit" エラーが発生する

Tags: android

Pixel デバイスのビルド番号 RQ1A.201205.003 以降で以下のエラーが発生します。
これは OS のバグか仕様変更か、情報がありましたら教えていただけませんでしょうか。

■コード

```
      ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
      String order = "date ASC limit 100";
      Cursor cursor = resolver.query(
          CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          order);
```

■エラー内容

```
"Invalid token limit,LINE:142,Method:readExceptionFromParcel Exception:Invalid token limit"
```

■このエラーが発生するビルド番号
2020年12月のアップデートから発生するようです。

```
https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/87641266
・RQ1A.201205.003
・RQ1A.201205.008
・RQ1A.201205.011

https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/93232095
・RQ1A.210105.002
・RQ1A.210105.003

https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/96244000
・RQ1A.210205.004
```

■limit 句を以下のコードに置き換えるとエラーは発生しません

```
buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("limit", "100")
```

■追記
公式ドキュメントの方式で実装すると、エラーは発生しませんが、`LIMIT` 句が動作しませんでした（全件取得されてしまう）。

[ContentProvider - query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.CancellationSignal))

```
 // Request 20 records starting at row index 30.
 Bundle queryArgs = new Bundle();
 queryArgs.putInt(ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_OFFSET, 30);
 queryArgs.putInt(ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_LIMIT, 20);
 
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
       contentUri,    // Content Uri is specific to individual content providers.
       projection,    // String[] describing which columns to return.
       queryArgs,     // Query arguments.
       null);         // Cancellation signal.
```

Comment: もしかしたらこれの承認回答では無く後から書かれたandroid 11から云々の回答が参考になるかも。[limiting number of rows in a ContentResolver.query() function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10390577/9014308)

Comment: @kunif 情報ありがとうございます。`Bundle()` で実装しても LIMIT できませんでした。コードについては質問に追記しております。

Comment: 他の質問のコメント欄にありました。appendQueryParameterでlimitを指定するのが、android開発側の意向なのかもしれません。
// Some apps are abusing "ORDER BY" clauses to inject "LIMIT"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640480/specifying-limit-offset-for-contentprovider-queries#comment114486251_12641015
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java#2234